# iOS 6 Auto Restart

Tags: ios, iphone

Ok here it is, when I updated my 3GS to iOS 6 there are times that my iPhone is freezing (when I used the "Tap to Tweet" button) and my iPhone just auto restarting for a couple of seconds. Is this auto restart thing is a new feature of iOS 6 or just a bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug, but may be specific to your iPhone (for whatever reason). Try to do a full restore via iTunes.

Comment: It’s definitively not a feature!

Comment: It's called a **respring**

Comment: I had the same problem with an Iphone 6, after using a couple of minutes is restarted,

Answer (score 1):

It may be an odd bug or a hardware failure or a sign that the OS didn't install correctly on your device.

You could look at the logs on the device or go through some of the troubleshooting steps to see if you need service or just to try restoring the OS again.

- Go to the express lane: https://expresslane.apple.com/GetproductgroupList.action
- Select **iPhone**
- Select **Service Requests & Troubleshooting**
- Select **Restore or update not working as expected**

I would send in the diagnostics and work through the steps listed. Alternatively, if your phone works for several minutes, you could also browse the error logs from Settings > General > About > Diagnostics & Usage > Diagnostics & Usage Data

Look for LatestCrash and panic entries first - and then perhaps other log files might be of use. These logs also can be synced to a computer for easier searching with iTunes, Xcode and other programs that read files from iOS devices.

Comment: Can Low in memory cause my phone to auto restart? BecauseI saw a lot of low memory in the diagnostics and it is dated yesterday. 12-27-12

Comment: Almost never is a Low-Memory error a problem. The system keeps everything in memory all the time and only removes programs (jettisons them) when another program needs memory. This can help for tuning the system since you might take longer to resume an app that is jettisoned and it also tells Apple (and you) which programs hog the most memory so they can get optimized to run better with less resources. The system almost never is so starved for memory that it doesn't keep running.